# Turn off redundant output in manage.py in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-manage.py, django-management-command

I see lots of redundant output from libraries like Pillow or requests when using them in management command in PyCharm 2017.2.4:

[image]

[image]

I did not configure any additional logging for this libraries. Is it possible to turn it off?